# Mapster not mapping derived class in a List c#

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, mapster

I have multiple classes implementing a base class, e.g.:

```cs
public abstract class Step
{
    public StepId Id {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;
    public StepType Type {get;set;}
}

public class SelectionStep : Step 
{
    public List<string> Selections {get; set;}
}

public class NumericStep : Step 
{
}
```

With the following Mapster configs:

```cs
config.NewConfig<SelectionStep, StepResponse>()
    .Map(dest => dest.Selections, src => src.Selections.Select(x => x.Value));

config.NewConfig<Step, StepResponse>()
    .Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id.Value.ToString())
    .Map(dest => dest.Type, src => src.Type.ToString());
```

When I map from one `SelectionStep` to `StepResponse` it's working
`_mapper.Map<StepResponse>(SelectionStep)`

When I map from `List<Step>` containing both `SelectionStep` and `NumericStep` models, it does not use the `SelectionStepConfig`.
`_mapper.Map<List<StepResponse>>(List<Step>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I changed my `Step` configuration to include the `SelectionStep` see below the new configs.

```
config.NewConfig<SelectionStep, StepResponse>()
    .Map(dest => dest.Selections, src => src.Selections.Select(x => x.Value));

config.NewConfig<Step, StepResponse>()
    .Include<SelectionStep, StepResponse>()
    .Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id.Value.ToString())
    .Map(dest => dest.Type, src => src.Type.ToString());
```